# Self-writed slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got problem. I created slider in vanilla js and mix jquery a little and it's works perfectly.  I have two arrows to get next or prev slide, and it's updated by setInterval. Could guess that not optimized at all. 
And questions is : how can I update my controls before click without setInterval. Thanks

```
function initSlider(elem,controlNext,controlPrev) {

  let courses = $(elem);
  let minSlides = 0;
  let maxSlides = 2;
  let next = document.querySelector(controlNext);
  let prev = document.querySelector(controlPrev);

  if($(window).width() < 1100) {
     minSlides = 1;
  }

  for(let course of courses) {
     fadeOut(course);
  }

  for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
     fadeIn(courses[i]);
  }


next.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(maxSlides === courses.length || maxSlides === courses.length + 1) {
       next.style.opacity = "0.24";
       next.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else {
       maxSlides+=2;

       minSlides+=2;

       for(let course of courses) {
          fadeOut(course);
       }

       for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
          fadeIn(courses[i])
       }
    }
})


prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(minSlides === 0 ) {
        prev.style.opacity = "0.24";
        prev.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else {
        maxSlides-=2;
        minSlides-=2;   

        for(let course of courses) {
            fadeOut(course);
        }

        for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
            fadeIn(courses[i]);
        }
    }
  })

setInterval(() => {
    if(minSlides === 0) {
        next.style.opacity = "1";
        next.removeAttribute("disable") 
        prev.style.opacity = "0.24";
        prev.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else if(maxSlides === courses.length || maxSlides === courses.length + 1) {
        next.style.opacity = "0.24";
        next.setAttribute("disable","true") 
        prev.style.opacity = "1";
        prev.removeAttribute("disable") 
    } else if(minSlides !== 0 && maxSlides !== courses){
        prev.style.opacity = "1";
        prev.removeAttribute("disable") 
        next.style.opacity = "1";
        next.removeAttribute("disable") 
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

p.s sry for bad eng

Comment: What do you mean by "before click" exactly? I suspect that what you need is to put the code currently inside the interval in a named function and call it at the end of your `prev` and `next` click handlers, but I want to be sure

Comment: I mean controls changed to disable when user clicked at button , but I need to update faster. (not by click) 
Right now setInterval works correctly , but I  just wanna use more optimized soluton.  I guess using setInterval is bad practice in case of optimize code, cause it's execute all time.

Comment: Using setInterval is fine. You want it to execute the function all the time since it's a slider which changes slide in a particular interval. There's nothing wrong I see in that.

Comment: I didnot get "update my controls before click" part. Please create a pen or something and try to show us the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your code that you want to update the buttons according to the slides display, you can put the code in your interval in a named function and call it after slides are changed.

**NOTE** that if there is extra code not shown here to switch slides automatically with another interval, you should also add the function call in it too:

```
function initSlider(elem,controlNext,controlPrev) {

  let courses = $(elem);
  let minSlides = 0;
  let maxSlides = 2;
  let next = document.querySelector(controlNext);
  let prev = document.querySelector(controlPrev);

  if($(window).width() < 1100) {
     minSlides = 1;
  }

  for(let course of courses) {
     fadeOut(course);
  }

  for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
     fadeIn(courses[i]);
  }

  function updateButtons() {
    if(minSlides === 0) {
        next.style.opacity = "1";
        next.removeAttribute("disable") 
        prev.style.opacity = "0.24";
        prev.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else if(maxSlides === courses.length || maxSlides === courses.length + 1) {
        next.style.opacity = "0.24";
        next.setAttribute("disable","true") 
        prev.style.opacity = "1";
        prev.removeAttribute("disable") 
    } else if(minSlides !== 0 && maxSlides !== courses){
        prev.style.opacity = "1";
        prev.removeAttribute("disable") 
        next.style.opacity = "1";
        next.removeAttribute("disable") 
    }
  }


  next.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(maxSlides === courses.length || maxSlides === courses.length + 1) {
       next.style.opacity = "0.24";
       next.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else {
       maxSlides+=2;

       minSlides+=2;

       for(let course of courses) {
          fadeOut(course);
       }

       for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
          fadeIn(courses[i])
       }
    }
    updateButtons(); //call it at the end
  });


  prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(minSlides === 0 ) {
        prev.style.opacity = "0.24";
        prev.setAttribute("disable","true") 
    } else {
        maxSlides-=2;
        minSlides-=2;   

        for(let course of courses) {
            fadeOut(course);
        }

        for(let i = minSlides; i < maxSlides; i++) {
            fadeIn(courses[i]);
        }
    }
    updateButtons(); //call it at the end
  });

}
```